# Eloquent whereHas and With()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What im trying is to get my AppNamespace, AppModule and AppController. So i use Laravel 5.2 with eloquent and run:

```
$this->namespaceModel->whereTitle( $this->namespace )
    ->whereHas( 'modules', function ( $q )
    {
        $q->whereTitle( $this->module );
    } )
    ->whereHas( 'modules.controllers', function ( $q )
    {
        $q->whereTitle( $this->controller );
    } )
    ->first();
```

This gives me a false or true depending on the results, but not the record itself. I've used a with() too but that doesnt return a record IF the whereHas() returns true. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use joins on that query like this:

```
$this->namespaceModel->whereTitle( $this->namespace )
    ->join( 'modules', 'namespaces.id', '=', 'modules.namespace_id')
    ->join( 'controllers', 'modules.id', '=', 'controllers.module_id')
    ->where( 'modules.title', $this->module )
    ->where( 'controllers.title', $this->controller )
    ->select('namespaces.*')
    ->with('modules', 'modules.controllers')
    ->first();
```

Comment: Thank you, fixed my problem :)